# Get Started button appears but posback not coming to server

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger-bot

Based on this documentation [Get Started Button - Messenger Platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/thread-settings/get-started-button) I have created a get started button. I got this result from CURL

```
{
   "result": "Successfully added new_thread's CTAs"
}
```

The button appears properly, but when clicking on the button the **`postback`** is not triggering in my **`webhook`**.

I have all the following fields in app settings

> message_deliveries, message_echoes, message_reads, messages,
>   messaging_account_linking, messaging_checkout_updates,
>   messaging_optins, messaging_payments, messaging_postbacks,
>   messaging_referrals

Other bot text processing works properly.

Anyone faced this issue?

----[EDIT]----
It seems there are multiple page access token assigned to the hook, for each page access token we need to set the menu.

I have deleted and re-created the app then it started working

Comment: Did you solve this problem?